# Rearrange column to come up with the best combinations that equals to 5000 or twos and threes cells vba

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have been trying to look for a vba code to rearrange column to match our target, I know solver is perhaps a solution but could not find any solution on the net or excel. example :

[image]

A vba runs and then rearrange to something like this:

[image]

The desired result is, each row adds up to 5000, number has to be used only once. If you have any idea please advice. (Please ignore the addition outcome, its for the explanation Only)

Answer (score 0):

The solution via Solver using least square method.

[image]

```
A2:B7, F1 - source data
C2:C7 - the result (initial values are 1 for all cells)
```

Formulas:

```
B8=SUM(B2:B7)
F2=ROUND(B8/F1,0)
F3=B8/F2
H2=IF(ROW()>$F$2+1,"",ROW()-1) - drag down till H7
I2=SUMIF($C$2:$C$7,H2,$B$2:$B$7) - drag down till I7
J2=IF(I2=0,0,(I2-$F$3)^2) - drag down till J7
J8=SUM(J2:J7)
```

Solver parameters:

```
Optimization: $J$8 => minimal value
Altered cells: $C$2:$C$7
Restrictions: $C$2:$C$7 is integer
              $C$2:$C$7 >= 1
              $C$2:$C$7 <= $F$2
```

The found solution on the screenshot.

Comment: Thank you for the Answer, the answer also complete the idea...